# Is it possible to downgrade an iPhone from iOS 8 to iOS 7?

Tags: iphone

iOS 8 in my iPhone 5 drains the battery, I'd like to return to iOS 7 if I can.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you on 8.0.2? The latest update (8.0.2) should have fixed a lot of battery problems.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

Apple has stopped 'signing' for iOS 7.

Unless some new 'method' is found, the change is irreversible.